# R ROracle dbWriteTable puts quotes around tables

Tags: r

Regarding ROracle library in R...

Every time I create a table using `dbWriteTable`, when I select it inside an Oracle Client I have to put quotes around the table name like:

```
select * from "table_name"
```

That is super annoying, how to get rid of the quotes? What do I need to tweak so that this works:

```
select * from table_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a bunch of things but this worked:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "MYTABLE", df, rownames = F, append = T, overwrite = F)
```

What is nice about this is that in case MYTABLE does not exist, it **creates it** for you. Now you can do:

```
select * from mytable;
```

//Edit:

If you create a table with this, it is important to ensure that your column names are upper case.

```
colnames(df) <- toupper(colnames(df)) # in R
dbWriteTable(conn, "MYTABLE", df, rownames = F, append = T, overwrite = F)

-- in SQL
select col1 from mytable; -- works
```

If you write the **column names as lowercase**, you will need to quote the columns in your select statement:

```
select "col1" from mytable; -- works
select col1 from mytable; -- doesn't work
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and feedback, I will give that a try!

Comment: ya, it seems that the table_name or column_name have to be created with (upper-case) to avoid using quotes around the columns.  Otherwise, it doesn't work.